# Failed prop type: The prop `options` is marked as required in `signupCheckBoxes`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was creating a react-native component when I received this error..

```
Failed prop type: The prop `options` is marked as required in `signupCheckBoxes`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

Basically, what I am doing is passing an array which contains types for the object I want to render

```
const inputFields = [
  {
    key: 'dob', 
    type: 'dateTyper', //change this to Dob component
    label: 'Your Date of birth',
    helper: 'Your Birthdate will help us in connecting you with people of similar age',
    required: true
  }, 
  {
    key: 'gender', 
    type: 'checkboxes', 
    label: 'Gender',
    required: true, 
    templateOptions: {
      multipleSelect: true,
      options: ['Male', 'Female', 'Others']
    }
  ]
```

and then mapping the component as user iterates through the array

```
   export const SignupFormComponent = (props) => {
        const {
        keyboardAutoOpenForText, 
        inputFields, 
        buttonStyle, 
        ProgressBarProps,  
        backgroundViewColor, 
        defaultColor, 
        helperTextStyle, 
        globalButtonText,
        buttonTextStyle,
        textStyle,
        onButtonClick,
        errorStyle,
        defaultErrorMessage
      } = props
           // All the component 
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
  const [payload, setPayloadData] = useState({})
  const [Loading, toggleLoadingData] = useState(false)
  const [Error, setErrorData] = useState({status: false, message: ''})
  // Current Component based on indux
  const currentComponent = inputFields[index]
  const {key, type, label, helper, buttonText} = currentComponent
  const templateOptions =  currentComponent.templateOptions || {}
  // if no template options, initlalize an empty object
  const {number, placeHolder, templateStyle, options}  = templateOptions
  const usedButtonText =  buttonText || globalButtonText
  // Setting up/mutating props 

  // --- Progress bar ---
  ProgressBarProps.currentProgress = index 
  ProgressBarProps.totalNumberOfProgressBars = inputFields.length
  ProgressBarProps.colorOfProgressBar = ProgressBarProps.colorOfProgressBar || defaultColor

  const onChangeHandler = (data, errorMessage=null) => {
    if (!errorMessage) {
      const currentData = {...payload}
      currentData[key] = data
      setPayloadData(currentData)
    } else {
      setErrorData({status: true, message: errorMessage})
    }
  }

  const getValueFromState  = async () => {
    setErrorData({status: false, message: ''})
    toggleLoadingData(true)
    const currentValue = payload[key]
    try {
      const eventTrack = await onButtonClick(index, key, currentValue, payload)
      if (index < inputFields.length) setIndex(index + 1)
      return toggleLoadingData(false)
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.message) setErrorData({status: true, message: error.message})
      else setErrorData({status: false, message: defaultErrorMessage})
      return toggleLoadingData(false)
    }
  }


          const mapSignUpComponents = {
            text: (
                <TextInput  
                  placeholder={placeHolder}
                  number={number}
                  style={[{color: defaultColor, borderColor: defaultColor}, styles.defaultTextInputStyle, templateStyle]}
                  onChangeText={text => onChangeHandler(text)}
                  value={payload[key] ? `${payload[key]}` : ''} // Doesn't seem right but otherwise the value of the text input also get mutate with other values
                />),
            dateTyper: (
              <DateTyper
              textInputStyle={[{color: defaultColor, width: (Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.6)/8 }, styles.nextInputStyle, templateStyle]} 
              upsideEmit={onChangeHandler}/>
            ),
            checkboxes: (
              <CheckBoxes 
              options={options}
              />
            )
          }


          const renderComponent = mapSignUpComponents[type]
          return (
               <View> 
               {renderComponent}
             <View>
          )
    }
```

Initially, the component should be dateTyper (`const renderComponent = mapSignUpComponents[type]`) so the `options` key isn't even required, hence options are `undefined`

the `options` is a required prop for `checkboxes` component, but since we aren't rendering it, I am not sure why i am getting the above error

I would so appreciate if someone could help me out to solve the same.

My checkbox component looks like this

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

const signupCheckBoxes = (props) => {
  const { options, multipleSelect} = props
  console.log(options)
  return (
    <View>
    <Text> Hello</Text>

    </View>
  )
}

signupCheckBoxes.propTypes = {
  options: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  multipleSelect: PropTypes.bool
}

signupCheckBoxes.defaultProps = {
  multipleSelect: true
}



export default signupCheckBoxes
```

Comment: If you run the code, do you get some logs from `singupCheckBoxes`? I think `signupCheckBoxes` is rendered somewhere.

Comment: templateOptions seems to be inside the input fields object.I think you can not access options like this,thats why it is giving undefined

Comment: @YonggooNoh Nope, Can't see any logs (added console log in `signupCheckBoxes ` but those logs weren't logging)

Comment: @warmachine Sorry, Can't comprehend your comment

Comment: const {number, placeHolder, templateStyle, options}  = templateOptions;
can you console after this line what you are getting?

Comment: `options` is undefined here

Comment: cause it is inside inputFields object right?so you can not destructure like that ,
assuming your data model will remain always same 

const  {options}=inputFields[1].templateOptions;
this will get the options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are doing `<CheckBoxes options={options} />` even if `options` is undefined. This basically translates to initialising that component (but not calling the render function). During initialisation, react will check that all required props are available which is then throwing an error.

To fix it, I would do the following:

```
const mapSignUpComponents = {
            text: (
                <TextInput  
                  placeholder={placeHolder}
                  number={number}
                  style={[{color: defaultColor, borderColor: defaultColor}, styles.defaultTextInputStyle, templateStyle]}
                  onChangeText={text => onChangeHandler(text)}
                  value={payload[key] ? `${payload[key]}` : ''} // Doesn't seem right but otherwise the value of the text input also get mutate with other values
                />),
            dateTyper: (
              <DateTyper
              textInputStyle={[{color: defaultColor, width: (Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.6)/8 }, styles.nextInputStyle, templateStyle]} 
              upsideEmit={onChangeHandler}/>
            ),
            checkboxes: options === undefined ? undefined : (
              <CheckBoxes 
              options={options}
              />
            )
          }
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a doc or article about the component initialization?

Comment: I don't think so. I found out about this behaviour by going through the generated JS code (from the JSX file).